# Swift function with Shorthand Argument Names

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to use Shorthand Argument Names with a Swift function. Closures have this feature, but since a function is in itself a closure, there might be a way to access parameters with name omitted. In detail here is what my query is:

You can implement a closure with shorthand argument name like this:

```
someFunction(param1, { $0 > $1 })
```

There is no need to provide parameter names in a closure, simply use $0, $1 etc.

For a function you may define it like so:

```
    func functionC(Int, String) {

    }
```

Omitting the param names here does not give any compiler error. Probably this is a swift feature. So does this mean I can access the params without name. If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bug or half implemented feature now because I can't find anything in the documentation about it. Using a function like you described compiles and runs fine:

```
func functionC(Int, String) {
    println("function called")
}
functionC(10, "hello")
```

but attempting to use the arguments with the closure syntax `$0` and `$1` results in the error: `Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure` which pretty clearly states you aren't allowed to use anonymous arguments in a function.

I think the purpose of this then is to be able to have the same method signature of a required function even if you don't have to use all of the arguments like this example:

```
protocol myProtocol{
    func requiredFunc(Int, String) -> Bool
}
class myClass: myProtocol{
    func requiredFunc(x: Int, String) -> Bool{
        return x > 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shorthand arguments in a closure because the compiler can infer the parameters and their types. But it is not fair to say that func functionC(Int, String) is the same as a closure with no parameter list. A closure declared the same way will not work either. Just like your function declaration, this closure is not valid because the parameters were declared:

```
 { (Int, String) -> Bool in
            return $0 > $1
 }
```

Comment: Hmmm... But why does the compiler is not giving any error? I feel its not giving any error because there might be a way to access the params.

Comment: I believe that it is not giving you an error for the reason that connor mentioned, and gave an example for, what you are doing is perfectly legal because you might not actually use the parameter(s).

Answer (score 0):

Short hand arguments don't work for functions. According to the compiler they work only for closures.
Coming to your stated case:

```
func functionC(Int, String) {

}
```

here it doesn't report any error because you just defined the function to take arguments of Int and String but cannot be used anywhere since they're not assigned. So there is no purpose to take this case other to verify how the compiler works.